# how to change the message in the alert that ask permission for notification?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, uilocalnotification

[image]

to send notification either push or local notification, we have to ask permission first to the user. and the alert will show up like the picture above that said

> "Notifications may include alerts, sounds, and icon badges. these can
>   be configured in settings"

can I customize this message? I want use my custom messsage in my local language. If I want to set the message for asking location when in use, I can set the message in the info.plist, but I can't find for this alert notification.

could you please tell me where I can find this one?

Comment: Apple controls what goes in there, so no. Also, unless you are working on behalf of the BBC, then their lawyers may want to have a word with you on this...

Comment: You can’t change that. It’s unique to Apple

Comment: @Lance Samaria, what if I want to write it in another language?

Comment: @Ahmadhassan read here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/85549 and the answer by eskimo here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/13155?answerId=36704022#36704022. Basically it seems the system's alert language is based on the user's device preference, so the devs can't change it.

Comment: I had another app that was rejected because the apple tester said the permission alerts was in English, not in Turkish

Comment: If they are based on the device settings and can’t be changed how could she/he reject it? You should post the rejection as a question with a screenshot of it and see if anyone encountered a similar problem. That’s very strange